# The command fig.show() returns an error in pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The following code produces an error:

```
x = np.arange(100)

fig = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
fig.show()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-528-6ebedab27258> in <module>
----> 1 fig.show()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'show'
```

What causes the error and how I should correct my code?

Comment: in the error `fig.show()` is the line in error and in the code there is no such line? What is the error exactly?

Comment: I want to plot the figure calling fig.show(). Instead of producing the plot, I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.subplots`, it is [returns](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots):

> fig : Figure
>
> axes.Axes object or array of Axes objects.

So if you assign the result of plt.subplots() to fig only, these two objects are stored in a tuple, and you cannot change the tuple, i.e cannot assign plots to axes. So usually it makes more sense to do:

```
x = np.arange(100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.plot(x)
fig.show()
```